# error when trying to run a test on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

for a month i'm using xcode and there are no problems. but now, when I'm trying to run a test of something I wrote, I get this message:

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of MobileSubstrate.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/Frameworks/CydiaSubstrate.framework/Libraries/SubstrateLoader.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of SubstrateLoader.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Activator.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of Activator.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
Couldn't register 'application' with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.(gdb)
```

What seems to be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: restart your device and Xcode then try again may help

Comment: I get a couple of such errors every time I start a test session.  Doesn't seem to cause any harm.

Comment: But that last error probably means precisely what it says -- another copy of the simulator is running.  "Quit" the simulator and try again.

Comment: This is because your test device is jail broken. MobileSubstrate is used by Cydia.